# Adding header block in soap message using Apache Camel

Tags: soap, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to add the following block in the soap-header of a soap message before consuming the service.

```
<login>
    <user>User</user>
    <password>Password</password>
</login>
```

**Expected Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <login>
            <user>User</user>
            <password>Password</password>
        </login>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <---Body of message----->
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am totally new to this and have not been able to find a working solution. Would be glad if someone could help.

Comment: I solved the question using jaxb and Properties annotation.

Comment: Can you post the solution as below?